# WatermarkedTextBox for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am looking for some kind of WatermarkedTextBox for Windows Phone 7? But I need a custom control not how to implement Watermark behavior or how to handle the GotFocus/LostFocus events.

Answer (score 7):

This has been added to the official [Windows Phone 7 Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), and as covered [here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-PhoneTextBox-in-depth).  It's called PhoneTextBox and can be used like:

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox Hint="Your Text Hint"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this [Watermark TextBox for Silverlight](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/swt62/archive/2009/08/16/watermark-textbox-for-silverlight.aspx) control, or [this one](http://silverscratch.blogspot.com/2010/03/watermarked-textbox-part-i.html). It's a popular control with [many implementations out there](http://www.bing.com/search?q=%2Bsilverlight+%2B3+%2Bwatermark+%2BTextBox&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC).