# How to create watermark in textbox using silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can someone explain to me how I could create a watermark in a textbox using silverlight?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WatermarkedTextBox for Windows Phone 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141325/watermarkedtextbox-for-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 6):

Here is what you need.
http://watermarktextbox.codeplex.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid x:Name="SearchPanel">
    <TextBox x:Name="txtQuery" Text="{Binding Query, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="8" Padding="3, 3, 21, 3"
        GotFocus="txtQuery_GotFocus" LostFocus="txtQuery_LostFocus"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="lblSearchStatus" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="13, 0"
        Text="Enter some text ..."
        IsHitTestVisible="False">
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Then hide lblSearchStatus in txtQuery_GotFocus and show it again in txtQuery_GotFocus. Could be also done via storyboard. The important part is setting IsHitTestVisible to false for the  TextBlock overlay.

Comment: Thanks Oliver for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I created a watermark TextBox and watermark PasswordBox.

It's available on NuGet: WindowsPhoneControls

You can look at the source here:

https://github.com/JoshClose/WindowsPhoneControls