# How to apply MaxLength to watermarkControl:WatermarkPasswordBox in C#?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, maxlength

So, I could use your help applying MaxLength="10" for this watermarkpasswordbox

```
<watermarkControls:WatermarkPasswordBox  
    x:Name="passwordLoginTextBox"  
    WatermarkText="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.PasswordWatermark, 
                            Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply this, in your code-behind file, add the following:

```
passwordLoginTextBox.MaxLength = 10;
```

Comment: No, I'm not near a PC right now, sorry! Do you get any kind of error message, or does it just not limit the length? Also, does it work ok if you put the MaxLength in the XAML?

Comment: Error 1 The property 'MaxLength' was not found in type 'WatermarkPasswordBox'.

Comment: OK, I was assuming the class had a MaxLength property, like a normal PasswordBox, but maybe not. Where did you get the control from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107808/how-to-create-watermark-in-textbox-using-silverlight

I created a watermark TextBox and watermark PasswordBox.

It's available on NuGet: WindowsPhoneControls

You can look at the source here:

https://github.com/JoshClose/WindowsPhoneControls

Comment: Strange, that control derives from TextBox, so MaxLength should work fine. I'll load it up on my PC...

Comment: Ok I see now, the control in the GitHub project derives from Control, which doesn't have a MaxLength property. You would have to extend the control yourself.

Comment: Can't really provide a complete code solution here, but algorithmically you would want to handle PreviewMouseDown messages, and decide what to do with the new character, based on the number of characters you already have. I think there's a way of 'throwing away' the new character so it's not added to the box, but I'm not sure. Alternatively you could just check the length of the string in the box each time the text string changes, and replace it with the text minus the last character, if it's too long.